# How to save change to textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to save changes to a item in a table and changes corresponding elements of `<p>` to `<textarea>` and then back, but currently it wont update.

Here is a example
https://jsfiddle.net/rajjejosefsson/qmeogxgL/12/

**JS**

```
$("td").on('click', '.js-edit', function() {
  $(this).text('Save Changes');
  $(this).addClass('js-save');

  var img = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.img-candy');
  console.log(img);
  var imgUrl = img.attr('src');

  var tr = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td p').replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<textarea />", '').append($(this).contents());
  });  
});


$("td").on('click', '.js-save', function() {

  $(this).text('Edit');
  $(this).removeClass('js-save');

  var tr = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td textarea').replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<p />", '').append($(this).contents());
  });

  var name = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.name-td').children('p').text();
  var price = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.price-td').children('p').text();
  var description = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.description-td').children('p').text();
  var img = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.img-candy').attr('src');

  var category_id = "a";
  var item_id = "a";
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the textarea.

Comment: Thanks just found out it by my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("td").on('click', '.js-save', function () {

            $(this).text('Edit');
            $(this).removeClass('js-save');


            var name = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.name-td').children('textarea').val();
            var price = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.price-td').children('textarea').val();
            var description = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.description-td').children('textarea').val();
            var img = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.img-candy').attr('src');

            var category_id = "1";
            var item_id = "99";


            var tr = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td textarea').replaceWith(function () {
                return $("<p />", '').append($(this).contents());
            });
        });
```